# Integral domain (rings and fields)

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, field-theory, integral-domain

Let $\mathbb Z[i]=\{a+ib \mid a, b \in \mathbb Z \}$. How to Show that $\mathbb Z[i]$ is a integral domain?

Comment: What have you tried? If you have some elements $a+bi$ and $c+di$ whose product is $0$, what equations does that give you for $a,b,c,d$?

Comment: Also, you need to show this is a commutative unital ring

Comment: Perhaps the easiest and shortest way: we have that $\;\Bbb Z[i]\le\Bbb C\;$ ,  and since the last one is a field we're done.

Answer (score 3):

$$ \mathbb{Z}[i] \cong \mathbb{Z}[x]/(x^2+1) $$  but $x^2 + 1 $ is irreducible in the UFD $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ so the ideal $ (x^2 + 1 )$ is prime and thus $ \mathbb{Z}[i] $ is a domain.

Comment: Good approach, but maybe to make it 100% plain, mention "$x^2+1$ is irreducible **in the UFD** $\Bbb Z[x]$, hence it is prime." As stated one could imagine a student starting to believe that irreducible elements of domains generate prime ideals :)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you gave shown it to be a ring, then you need to show that there are no zero divisors. What it means is to show that no two non-zero complex numbers can be multiplied to produce $0$.